# 3296 trimpot adjustment

Tags: resistors, potentiometer

I've got a 3296 trimpot like this one:

http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/78495/BOURNS/3296.html

I don't know whether clockwise or counter-clockwise increases or decreases the resistance?

[image: trimpot explanation from datasheet]

Is there anyway I can test?

BTW, it is already soldered to a component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define an increment or decrement of the resistance, all that you do by turning the trimmer screw is move the wiper toward one or the other end.
Depending on the way the trimmer is wired the rotation direction can have a specific meaning.

The direction of the wiper movement is already shown in the graph you have provided, turning the screw clockwise moves the wiper (pin 2) towards the end named 3 and turning it counterclockwise moves it towards the end named 1.

Comment: So, it is "neutral" so to speak? It is not like a potentiometer?

Comment: @fizzydrink It is the same with a potentiometer, the wiper movement doesn't increment/decrement the pot resistance, all it does is move the wiper toward one of the other end. If you connect ground to one end and a voltage to the other end then the wiper becomes the middle point of a voltage divider and the output changes based on the actual position. Depending on which end you connect the ground and voltage you get a different effect for the same rotation direction. Another option is to bridge one of the ends with the wiper in which case you get the effect of changing the equivalent resistance

Comment: Ah, OK. If I may, one last question: I have a constant current driver for LED with a trimpot to select the output current. How can I measure what it is outputting before connecting to the LED? I don't want to kill the LED in case it is too high?

Comment: @fizzydrink Does it have any specs/datasheet? Is it intended for one led, a series of leds?

Comment: It is a simple constant current boost driver. Not made specifically for LEDs. You can find it here: http://www.ebay.com/itm/DC-to-DC-10-32V-to-10-46V-150W-Boost-constant-current-power-supply-Regulator/350991436939?_trksid=p2047675.c100011.m1850&_trkparms=aid%3D222006%26algo%3DSIC.FITP%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D18775%26meid%3D4713447348454144646%26pid%3D100011%26prg%3D8532%26rk%3D0%26rkt%3D10%26sd%3D261364594526 . It can output 46V max @ 4A / 8A. (Adjustable via the 3296 trimpot)

Comment: @fizzydrink judging from [this image](http://postimg.org/image/5m31t6vjp/) pins 1 and 2 are already bridged so the CC pot works as a variable resistor, turning it clockwise decreases the resistance and turning it counterclockwise increases the resistance. I would expect the counterclockwise direction to reduce the current but I can't be sure. You can use a resistor as a load and measure the output.

Comment: Will a 3W 1 Ohm resistor work? Or will it explode?

Comment: @fizzydrink that is too low, the output is rated 10-46V so 10 Ohm/10W should do.